# git patch apply leading to conflicts?

Tags: git

We need to upgrade the kernel for android from `<REV1>` to `<REV2>`.

I am trying to generate a list of patches between two `<REV1>` and `<REV2>`.
So I checked if both are on the same branch to get that list of patches using command

```
$git merge-base 69ecc39b5b4ea78de1f25bf9cbe7c236a91f764c af5ddc99f3d0e7c2406d5bf64763eef7d0843127
```

and found that they are not on same branch.
as I got the  first common ancestor of `<REV1>` and `<REV2>` as c4b646ff80f558010ee486421ee1b718db1a3193

So I tried to generate  a list of patches between the common ancestor and `<REV2>` using

```
$git format-patch c4b646ff80f558010ee486421ee1b718db1a3193..af5ddc99f3d0e7c2406d5bf64763eef7d0843127 -o patch_JUN15_NOV26
```

Now I created a new branch and reset that to common ancestor commit

```
$git reset --hard c4b646ff80f558010ee486421ee1b718db1a319
```

Now I tried to patch the whole list of patches on this branch:

```
$git am --ignore-whitespace --reject ../../jb/kernel/patch_JUN15_APR10/*
```

But I got patch failed error asking me to resolve the conflicts for the first patch in the patchlist .
But I expect no conflicts. My assumption is that if `<REV1>` and `<REV2>` are on the same branch, then the generated patch list from format-patch can be applied back on `<REV1>` smoothly without conflicts.

Is my assumption correct?
Am I doing it the right way?

Comment: Why are you working with patch files? Is `git merge` not an option for you?

Comment: Its a big repository . And  I cant resolve all  conflicts. Later point if we want to debug any issue , patch list will be very helpful  to trace back the issue

Comment: Then perhaps rebase? With Git, you shouldn't really have to work with patch files anymore.

Comment: Is there a reason `git log -p <REV1>..<REV2>` is insufficient?

Answer (score 1):

#### The straight git answer, probably wrong:

Create new branch `merge-branch` at `REV2`, then rebase the `REV2` changes newer than the ancestor (and thus not in `REV1`) over top of `REV1`:

```
git checkout -b merge-branch <rev2-hash>
git rebase <ancestor-hash> --onto <rev1-hash>
             ^                        ^
             |                         \
             |                          `play them on top of this
              `take commits from this
               far back in the current branch

      ... and plant the result as the replacement for the current branch
```

#### The bigger picture:

Why the above answer is probably wrong is because, I'm guessing, like many, you're a small organization who maintains some customizations of the kernel for your product, and you want to upgrade to a newer kernel.  You based your customizations on `REV1` and now you would like to move that work to `REV2`. If that is the case, then dealing with the merge between `REV1` and `REV2` is *completely the wrong problem*.  This has already been taken care of upstream. Upstream has produced two perfectly good kernels: `REV1` and `REV2`. `REV1` isn't a direct ancestor of `REV2`, because those kernels are actually branches. But you don't have to deal with these change management details.  All you need to do is rebase your changes that were done against `REV1` on top of `REV2`.

Suppose you have `ourbranch` of kernel development which sprouted from `REV1`:

First, create a clone of `ourbranch` called `ourbranch-REV2`:

```
git checkout -b ourbranch-REV2 ourbranch
```

Now, rebase the `ourbranch` changes that are new since `REV1` (i.e. only our local changes), on top of the `REV2` kernel:

```
git rebase REV1 --onto REV2
```

If all goes well, you have `ourbranch-REV2` which is your `ourbranch` history rewritten as if it had been developed over the `REV2` kernel.